# Check which is the last cell in a specific column which has a value and select the cell below it in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to write some code to get the last cell in a specific column (e.g Column A) which has a value. I only know this:

```
Cells(3, 2).Value = quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the last row use below formula

```
lastRow = Cells(rows.count,1).End(xlUp).row
```

- rows.count = total number of rows in that version of Excel (65k in
  2003 etc) , i.e the last row in that verison of Excel
- 1 on the right of rows.count = Column A, 2 would be coulmn B and so on
- xlUp roughly means it will search bottom to up

You can search more if you would like on this command.

Now once you know the last row, then to fetch the value of it use

```
Variable = Cells(lastRow,1).Value
```

Comment: Is there a manual anywhere to find those commands. Like xlup etc.

Comment: I Google it but I did not find anything.  I didn't tryied yet I will tells in an hour

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the row for the last cell in a range it is better to use the find function.

As an example: For a specific column n; use the code below to set it to quantity

```
Dim n As Long, quantity As Long
n = 3
quantity = 5000
Cells(Columns(n).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row, n).Value = quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this which checks:

- there is at least one value in column  A (else no selection)
- that the last value is not in the last row (avoiding an error when trying to offset a row)

*code*

```
Sub LastRow()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Columns("A").Find("*", [a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    If rng1.Row <> Rows.Count Then rng1.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End If
End Sub
```